# Thumbnail Card context.Wait()

Tags: c#, botframework

I would like to ask how do I properly use a thumbnail card button. I want the button to specifically call a new method with context.Wait(methodName). 
Right now I have this code for thumbnail card buttons:

```
thumbnailCard.Buttons = new[] {new CardAction(
                        ActionTypes.MessageBack, $"Account", value: id
                        )};
var msg = context.MakeMessage();
msg.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
msg.Attachments = cardAttachment.ToList();

await context.PostAsync(msg);
context.Wait(methodName); **I want this to be called when button was clicked**
```

But apparently I can't fire the method whenever I click the button. PS: I am actually new to bot framework so any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Note: The possible duplicate is not the issue I am having. I am not calling a method via thumbnail.Buttons, but rather I am inserting the value needed to be passed onto another method using `context.Wait(MethodName)` but we have the same method on how to implement it properly, yet it doesn't answer the question why I wasn't able to fireback the method I inserted to context.Wait.

Comment: you have to place the method you want to call on a MessageReceived method, with a check on the value you receive (that should match what you are passing in the CardAction)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a specifc callback when clicking in Card Action - Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40808192/how-to-call-a-specifc-callback-when-clicking-in-card-action-bot-framework)

Comment: @NicolasR I have tried this however it did not worked on my end.

Comment: @EzequielJadib Oh, a duplicate, my bad, but what was suggested there didn't solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @RexHope, that's the problem of questions asked without the necessary code to reproduce and full context, we cannot give an appropriate response. Hopefully you got it on your own

Comment: @NicolasR My fault then. Yes, I solved it on my own, I used `ActionTypes.PostBack` instead of `MessageBack` and `ImBack`

Comment: In fact there are sometimes problems with PostBack on some channels for example, so your problem could have several causes (that's why I was only commenting and not posting an answer)

Comment: @NicolasR I see. Well, I will try to get back to that, but before I was scratching my head off while trying to solve the problem, because I have tried your solution and other solutions that I have found here, and other references but I just can't get it to work, anyway, I'll look into it if ever I happen to encounter it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the response everyone. I have fixed the issue by using `ActionTypes.PostBack`and did not used neither `MessageBack` nor `ImBack`.

And yes, I still did make use of `Context.Wait(method)`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need to use `context.Wait`  or is that just what you are trying?  You can use it, but it is going to wait on the message after the button click so it doesn't seem like that is exactly what you want.  Please respond and I can adjust my answer as you actually need it.

It Seems like you just want to execute a method after a button click.  For that you can use the following code and adjust it as you need, this is the simplest implementation I could think of.  please let me know if you have any follow up questions or need something else:

```
    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, 
    IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;
        var response = activity.CreateReply();

        IMessageActivity reply = context.MakeMessage();


        if (activity.Text.ToLowerInvariant() == "do stuff")
        {

            activity.CreateReply("I have done the stuff");
            await context.PostAsync(activity);
        }
        else
        {
            List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();

            CardAction Button = new CardAction
            {
                Title = "do stuff",
                //Type = ActionTypes.ImBack;  //this will display "do stuff" in the chat window
                Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,  //same behavior except "do stuff" not displayed
                Value = "do stuff"
            };

            cardButtons.Add(Button);

            HeroCard Card = new HeroCard()
            {
                Buttons = cardButtons
            };
            Attachment plAttachment = Card.ToAttachment();

            reply.Attachments.Add(plAttachment);

            await context.PostAsync(reply);
        }

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response. I have fixed this by using postback and not using messagereceivedasync method to check what the value did my rich card passed to. Thanks.